# help with regex - extracting text

Tags: regex, bash, sed, bibtex

Suppose I have some text files (f1.txt, f2.txt, ...) that looks something like

```
@article {paper1,
author = {some author},
title = {some {T}itle} ,
journal = {journal},
volume = {16},
number = {4},
publisher = {John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.},
issn = {some number},
url = {some url},
doi = {some number},
pages = {1},
year = {1997},
}
```

I want to extract the content of title and store it in a bash variable (call it $title), that is, "some {T}itle" in the example.  Notice that there may be curly braces in the first set of braces.  Also, there might not be white space around "=", and there may be more white spaces before "title".

Thanks so much.  I just need a working example of how to extract this and I can extract the other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
title=$(sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*title[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*{/ {s///; s/}[^}]*$//p}' inputfile)
```

Explanation:

- `/^[[:blank:]]*title[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*{/ {` - If a line matches this regex

  - `s///` - delete the matched portion
  - `s/}[^}]*$//p` - delete the last closing curly brace and every character that's not a closing curly brace until the end of the line and print
- `}` - end if

Comment: +1 After I changed my script to take care of the case where a comma could exist in the value I got exactly your script.  I've told the OP to accept yours but I think you should wrap it `title=$(sed ...)` to completely meet his requirements.

Answer (score 2):

```
title=$(sed -n '/title *=/{s/^[^{]*{\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/;s/} *$//p}' ./f1.txt)
```

1. `/title *=/`: Only act upon lines which have the word 'title' followed by a '=' after an arbitrary number of spaces
2. `s/^[^{]*{\([^,]*\),.*$/\1/`: From the beginning of the line look for the first '{' character. From that point save everything you find until you hit a comma ','. Replace the entire line with everything you saved
3. `s/} *$//p`: strip off the trailing brace '}' along with any spaces and print the result.
4. `title=$(sed -n ... )`: save the result of the above 3 steps in the bash variable named `title`

Comment: Thanks.  However, what if there are commas in what I want to capture?  Then it doesn't work because of the "first comma" logic.  How can we incorporate the flexibility of additional commas?  Thanks

Comment: @Vinh you should accept Dennis' answer because after I changed my script to take care of the case where a comma could be in the name, I got exactly his script.  The only thing you need to do is wrap his script in `$()` like mine is.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely more elegant ways, but at 2:40AM:

```
title=`cat test | grep "^\s*title\s*=\s*" | sed 's/^\s*title\s*=\s*{?//' | sed 's/}?\s*,\s*$//'`
```

Grep for the line that interests us, strip everything up to and including the opening curly, then strip everything from the last curly to the end of the line